# Runtime Error 91 when sorting

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a subroutine to dynamically copy 2 columns from one sheet to another. These column lengths might change from one report to another.

Here is the code:

---

```
Sub getAnalystsCount()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Dim varray As Variant, element As Variant

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ReportData")

    With ws
        Worksheets("ReportData").Activate

    Columns("E:E").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ReportData").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ReportData").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
        Range("E1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ReportData").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


    '~~> Set First row
    firstrow = 2

    '~~> Set your range
    Set rng = .Range("E" & firstrow & ":E" & lastrow)

    varray = rng.Value

    'Generate unique list and count
    For Each element In varray
        If dict.Exists(element) Then
            dict.Item(element) = dict.Item(element) + 1
        Else
            dict.Add element, 1
        End If
    Next
End With

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Analysts")

With ws
    Worksheets("Analysts").Activate

    'Paste report somewhere
    ws.Range("A3").Resize(dict.Count, 1).Value = _
        WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Keys)
    ws.Range("B3").Resize(dict.Count, 1).Value = _
        WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Items)
     ......
```

the error is in this line:

```
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ReportData").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
```

Comment: If you are going to use autofilter, that isn't the same as sorting. You only need to write `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ReportData").AutoFilter` to reset any sorting. Based on your current code, just remove `.AutoFilter` from everywhere and fix a range to sort and you will be able to get it to run.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your below code

```
Columns("E:E").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ReportData").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ReportData").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
        Range("E1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ReportData").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

With the below code

```
Columns("E:E").Select
lastrow1 = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ReportData").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ReportData").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E1") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ReportData").Sort
    .SetRange Range("E2:E" & lastrow1)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: The above code worked.Thank you all for your replies guys. i really appreciate all your help.

Comment: Thanks @user3930696. Please accept and vote up the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
startCell = Range("A1").Address
endCell = Range("E100000").End(xlUp).Address
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ReportData").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ReportData").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending,  DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ReportData").Sort
    .SetRange Range(startCell,endCell)
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Obviously this is rough, you will need to make it your own, but it will allow you to sort the E column which is what your initial code looks like it was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The [Range.Sort method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx) can be used for a quick one column sort and discards much of the verbose code produced when recording a worksheet sort operation. Without an active [AutoFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844.aspx), this is the better way to go.

```
Sub getAnalystsCount()
    Dim el As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim varray As Variant

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    'don't know what is in column E but this might be helpful
    'dict.comparemode = vbTextCompare  'non-case-sensitive

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ReportData")
    With ws
        'this is not necessary inside a With ... End With block
        'Worksheets("ReportData").Activate
        With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            'this quick code line is all you need
            .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(5), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
            'resize to # of rows -1 × 1 column and shift 1 row down and over to column E
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 4)
                'store the raw values
                varray = .Value2
            End With
        End With
    End With 'done with the ReportData worksheet

    'Generate unique list and count
    'I prefer to work with LBound and UBound
    For el = LBound(varray, 1) To UBound(varray, 1)
        If dict.Exists(varray(el, 1)) Then
            dict.Item(varray(el, 1)) = dict.Item(varray(el, 1)) + 1
        Else
            dict.Add Key:=varray(el, 1), Item:=1
        End If
    Next el

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Analysts")
    With ws
        'this is not necessary inside a With ... End With block
        'Worksheets("Analysts").Activate

        'might want to clear the destination cell contents first if there is something there
        if application.counta(.Range("A3:B3") = 2 then _
            .Range("A3:B" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents

        'Paste report somewhere
        .Range("A3").Resize(dict.Count, 1).Value = _
            WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Keys)
        .Range("B3").Resize(dict.Count, 1).Value = _
            WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Items)
    End With 'done with the Analysts worksheet

End Sub
```

I prefer to work with the [LBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a7w1ac(v=vs.90).aspx) and [UBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278658.aspx) functions to determine the scope of an array.

When you are inside a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx), use the `.` to note the parent worksheet and discard the [Range .Activate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221681.aspx) method and `ws` variable.